# Regular Expression to Retrieve text between two html tags with Visual Studio's search-replace feature

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to use Visual Studio's search-replace function to remove  tags that don't do anything.  The intent is to simplify some HTML before I paste it into a SharePoint page.

This is what I'm using in the Find box `\<font\>{~(.*\<font\>.*)}\</font\>`

And the Replace box has `\1`

However, the expression comes up with no matches, even though I have plenty of places like this `<font> xxxx </font>` within the HTML.  I could move the `.*` outside the paranthesis, but then the expression matches most of the line where I have multiple sets of font tags - some which actually do something.

I'm thinking this would be much easier if the IDE used the same regular expression engine as the languages for which it is the primary development tool.

Comment: I'd recommend copy/pasting the HTML into something like notepad++, do the search/replace there, and then paste to your final destination.

Comment: I have TextPad, but it's regex engine can't solve this problem.
Other than multiple versions of Visual Studio, my other editors are WordPad and MS Word - those can't solve this either.

Comment: At the time I asked this question, I was using Visual Studio 2010.  Later on, I began using Visual Studio 2012 for some SharePoint development.  Microsoft granted my wish!  Now Visual Studio uses the same regular expression language as the .Net RegEx class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to review the documentation for VS 2010.  Using a minimal match `@` was all I needed: `\<font\>{.@}\</font\>`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to replace all span tags with div tags. I was able to solve a similar problem by using the following RegEx in the picture. I had to escape both the > and < and the class attribute double quotes.
`\<span class=\"label\"\>{.@}\</span\>`
`<div class="label">\1<\div>`

[image: Html Tags RegEx Replacement]